# Image url passing null value to another Intent

Tags: java, php, android, sql, android-volley

I have implemented RecyclerView in my app and have setup a onClickListener on Recycler View. The text fields are passing successfully, however I also have a image in the recyclerview, which is being brought through picasso. So I try to retrieve the image url which is stored in another class, but I'm getting a empty value.

The code is:

```
package xyz.xyz;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FlatSearchCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FlatSearchCardAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private Context context;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
List<FlatCardItemReturn> flatlistCard;




public FlatSearchCardAdapter(List<FlatCardItemReturn> flatlistCard, Context context){
    super();
    //Getting all the superheroes
    this.flatlistCard = flatlistCard;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.flatrenter_list_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn =  flatlistCard.get(position);






    Picasso.with(context).load(flatcarditemreturn.getImageUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.loadingpicasso).error(R.drawable.errorpicasso).resize(100, 100).into(holder.imageView);


    holder.textViewId.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getId());
    holder.textViewType.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getType());

    holder.textViewFurnishing.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getFurnishing());
    holder.textViewArea.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getArea());
    holder.textViewPrice.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getPrice());
    holder.textViewNumberofrooms.setText(flatcarditemreturn.getNumberofrooms());








}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return flatlistCard.size();
}

public static class  ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{



    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView textViewType;
    public TextView textViewPrice;
    public TextView textViewFurnishing;
    public TextView textViewArea;
    public TextView textViewNumberofrooms;
    public TextView textViewId;

    public FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn = new FlatCardItemReturn();






    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);





        textViewId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flatphoto);
        textViewType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        textViewFurnishing = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.furnishing);
        textViewArea = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.area);
        textViewPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        textViewNumberofrooms = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numberofrooms);





        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), flatrenterpostview.class);
                i.putExtra("idvalue", textViewId.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("typevalue", textViewType.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("furnishingvalue", textViewFurnishing.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("areavalue", textViewArea.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("pricevalue", textViewPrice.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("numberofroomsvalue", textViewNumberofrooms.getText().toString());
                i.putExtra("imageurl", flatcarditemreturn.getImageUrl());








                v.getContext().startActivity(i);

            }
        });


    }


}
}
```

I'm pretty confused on how to set the position in that, so as to get the currect value. Will be grateful if anyone can help me out.
Just to make it clear, i.putExtra("imageurl", flatcarditemreturn.getImageUrl()); is giving nothing. I expect the url stored in my class. The url is stored perfectly, I checked.

Comment: If that's an adapter... where is your position? itemView is not holding any position so far.

Answer (score 1):

> Just to make it clear, `i.putExtra("imageurl", flatcarditemreturn.getImageUrl());` is giving nothing. I expect the url stored in my class

Then why do you create a new `FlatCardItemReturn` in your `ViewHolder`? This line:

```
public FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn = new FlatCardItemReturn();
```

You'll want to set the correct data item to the `ViewHolder`, rather that instantiating a new 'empty' one. You can easily accomplish this by adding a method to the `ViewHolder`:

```
public void setData(FlatCardItemReturn item) {
    flatcarditemreturn = item;
}
```

Now, just call this from `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn =  flatlistCard.get(position);

    // other stuff omitted

    holder.setData(flatcarditemreturn);
}
```

You can now also change:

```
public FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn = new FlatCardItemReturn();
```

into:

```
public FlatCardItemReturn flatcarditemreturn;
```